# What happens to the scheduler when an actor system shuts down?

Tags: scala, akka

I am running into some issues when testing an actor that uses the actor system's scheduler.  I had expected the scheduler to stop sending scheduled messages when the system gets shutdown after every test, but this does not seem to happen. I intend to change my test to use a mock scheduler, but I still have a few questions:

1. Why is the scheduler still sending messages after the system it belongs to is shutdown?
2. Can I add anything to afterAll to properly shutdown the scheduler before running another test?

Here is a working example using Akka 2.1:

```
import akka.testkit._
import akka.actor._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.language.postfixOps
import org.scalatest._

class MyActor(scheduler : Scheduler) extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case msg => {
      scheduler.schedule(0 millis, 1000 millis, sender, msg)
    }
  }
}

class MyActorSpec(_system: ActorSystem) extends TestKit(_system)
  with WordSpecLike
  with ImplicitSender
  with BeforeAndAfterAll{

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("TestSystem"))

  override def afterAll {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }

  trait Env{   
    val scheduler = system.scheduler  
    val testRef = TestActorRef(new MyActor(scheduler))
  }

  "MyActor" must {

    "schedule any received messages to be repeatedly sent back to the sender" in new Env{
      testRef ! "hello"
      expectMsg("hello")
    }

    "not send any messages when it hasn't been sent anything" in new Env{
      expectNoMsg
    }
  }
}
```

The second test fails because the scheduler is still sending "hello" msgs from the first test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are seeing here is an issue that comes from using the `ImplicitSender` trait.  When using this with `TestKit`, there is a sender `ActorRef` that is scoped at the class level and not scoped down to each individual test (like the stuff in `Env`).  Because this implicit sender is shared across the two tests, it makes the negative assertion of not getting any messages not work.  One possible workaround would be to stop using `ImplicitSender` and instead be explicit with a sender scoped down to the `Env` like this:

```
class MyActorSpec(_system: ActorSystem) extends TestKit(_system)
  with WordSpecLike
  with BeforeAndAfterAll{

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("TestSystem"))

  override def afterAll {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }

  trait Env{  
    val senderProbe = TestProbe()
    implicit val sender = senderProbe.ref 
    val scheduler = system.scheduler  
    val testRef = TestActorRef(new MyActor(scheduler))
  }

  "MyActor" must {

    "schedule any received messages to be repeatedly sent back to the sender" in new Env{
      testRef ! "hello"
      senderProbe.expectMsg("hello")
    }

    "not send any messages when it hasn't been sent anything" in new Env{
      senderProbe.expectNoMsg
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. So then I guess it had nothing to do with the scheduler? Should I edit the question to reflect this?

Comment: @mushroom, probably as this question is more about test scoping with Akka and TestKit.

Comment: So, I did some additional tests, and the scheduler still seems to exhibit the behavior I described (sending messages after the system terminates). I am accepting your answer because my tests are no longer broken, but I am still curious about why the scheduler seems to persist after the actor system shuts down.